# Mapping linux user to windows NFS exported share

Tags: linux, windows, nfs

I shared a Windows 2012 directory using NFS using this configuration:

[image]

Now, from the Linux side I can mount it using this command:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.0.20:/SHARED /mnt/windows_shared
```

Then, when I do an `ls -lah /mnt/windows_shared` I get a `Permission denied` error, and with `sudo ls -lah /mnt/windows_shared` I get this:

```
total 18M
drwx------ 2 4294967294 4294967294 4,0K feb  6  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root       root       4,0K sep 21 08:29 ..
-rwx------ 1 4294967294 4294967294  862 oct 11  2016 certificate.pem
-rwx------ 1 4294967294 4294967294 2,3M mar  2  2017 report.pdf
-rwx------ 1 4294967294 4294967294  598 ago  9 11:57 initialization.ini
drwx------ 2 4294967294 4294967294   64 feb  6  2018 client
-rwx------ 1 4294967294 4294967294 625K ago  4  2015 report2.pdf
drwx------ 2 4294967294 4294967294   64 sep 18 18:44 photos
drwxrwx--- 2 4294967294 4294967294 128K sep 18 10:48 another_file
```

I need to be able to mount and access the shared folder with a specific Linux user (without `sudo`), also the owner and group should be displayed correcly, not those `4294967294`. How can I do that?.

Comment: did you try as root to chmod the base directory? Basically use chmod/chown, as if you didn't know the server was Windows, and see what happens.

Comment: yes, but that only changes the base directory.

Comment: shit, that changed the permissions also from the Windows side.

Comment: So maybe you'll have to see how to not use the option unmapped access and see permissions. But now it's not a client problem anymore, but a (windows) server. (and if it turns into NFS4 it might become both' problem, which won't help)

Comment: Yes, I have access to both machines, so I can configure the Windows side. Part of the question is how can I configure the Windows machine to allow a Linux user to see the correct user and group in the file list.

Comment: Yes but this *probably*  can't be answered on UL SE which deals with Unix/Linux. Maybe SU or SF (if that's done in a professional environment). That's what I really meant with my previous comment.

Comment: To move this post "from Unix&Linux to ServerFault" shouldn't it be deleted here, so it's not cross-posted anymore? Also you should add to the question there what happened in comments here since it appears to matter for the answer.